# Loop through jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I had a requirement that if user enters a date in  'EarliestReasonableOfferDate'   it should prompt a dialog yes/no. if yes is selected it continues if no the user should pick the value and store in a hidden field 'OfferedDate' and clear the datepicker. The user then needs to enter second offered date and then a dialog should appear as user accepted the second offer date, if yes it continues and if no the datepicker value should be cleared and the entered value should store in offerdate field as a comma seperated string. and so as third and fourth. Here is my code. I am struggling to loop over the dialogs.

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.OfferedDate) %>                    
      <td>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(M => M.EarliestReasonableOfferDate,"DateTime")%>
    </td>  

    $("#EarliestReasonableOfferDate").bind('change', function () {
        AcceptDialog();   
    });

    function AcceptDialog() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    $(div)
    .html('Did Patient Accept First date Offered? Yes/No')
    .dialog({
     modal: true,
     title: 'Acceptence Screen',
     buttons: {
     "Yes": function () {

       $(this).dialog('close');
       },

      "No": function () {

        var hv = $('#EarliestReasonableOfferDate').val();
        var hv1 = $('#OfferedDate').val(hv);
        $('#EarliestReasonableOfferDate').val('');

        var hvappend = hv1.val() + ',';
         alert(hvappend);
       $(this).dialog('close');
        alert("Enter Next date Offered");            


     }
    }
    });
    }
```

eg., The result of above is  Offerdate ='06/06/2013,'
 but  i need the result of loop  offerdate = '06/06/2013,07/07/2013,07/08/2013'

Comment: Can you explain your requirement through example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just an idea, but are you creating multiple fields with the same ID?  Your $("#EarliestReasonableOfferDate") selector seems to indicate that.  jQuery doesn't like that.

Comment: @vinothini check : jsfiddle.net/w8sPN/15 user enters the first date dailog 'Did offer 1 accepted?' with yes/no prompts. when no, prompts 'Enter next date' and ok the first date is saved. user enters second date dailog with 'Did offer 2 accepted?' with yes/no prompts. when no, 'Enter next date' and ok the second date is saved after the comma and so on till user accepts yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having trouble with opening more dialogs? Cause you can just call the function recursively. Threw this code together to show you how you can keep showing the dialog over and over and it would append what is in the offer text field. If you need a separate dialog between the Yes/No to input the date then they can just call each other.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8sPN/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function(){offer_popup(1);});  
});

function offer_popup(level){
 $("#dialogb") 
    .dialog({
     modal: true,
     title: 'Acceptence Screen',
        open: function(){
            $("#offertext").text("Did user accept offer " + level + "? Yes/No");
        },
     buttons: {
     "Yes": function () {

       $(this).dialog('close');
       },

      "No": function () {
          $("#oldoffers").text( $("#oldoffers").text()+ ", " + $("#offer").val());
          $("#offer").val('');
           $(this).dialog('close');
            offer_popup(level+1);           


     }
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its really helpful. yes i  need a separate dialog between the Yes/No to input the date .please also help to call each other.

Comment: Instead of start button in your example is it possible a datepicker? and the popups should be only  yes/no dailogs and ok popup if user accepts any inbetween the first,second,third etc

Comment: check : http://jsfiddle.net/w8sPN/15/ user enters the first date dailog 'Did offer 1 accepted?' with yes/no prompts. when no, prompts 'Enter next date' and ok the first date is saved. user enters second date dailog with 'Did offer 2 accepted?' with yes/no prompts. when no, 'Enter next date' and ok the second date is saved after the comma and so on till user accepts  yes.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `hvappend` is wrong. You never append anything to it. you should do something like this:

```
function AcceptDialog() {
    var hvappend = "";
    ... 
    .dialog({
       ...
         "No": function () {
            ...
            hvappend += hv1.val() + ',';
            ...
        })
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The way you've implemented the function, `hvappend` is overwritten on every iteration of the function.